# Unexpected scrolling when tabbing through form fields in slider (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll, onfocus

I have a form inside of a JavaScript slider.  **If I use the tab key to give focus to a form field that already has content, the browser unexpectedly scrolls the slider.**  I have only seen this in Chrome (Version 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04).  I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this, and if so were you able to find a work around?

Here is a code snippet I used to reproduce the issue and narrow down the contributing conditions (also at http://jsfiddle.net/gkorban/jtuo5my0/6/):

```css
.viewport {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 600px;
}
.form-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
input {
  width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <form action="#">
        <input type="text" name="field1" />
        <input type="text" name="field2" value="field 2" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Click on field 1, then press tab to give focus to field 2.</p>
```

I've been able to narrow the conditions to the following:

- Parent div is using overflow:hidden
- Child div is wider than parent div
- Using tab key to change field focus
- Form field receiving focus already has a value
- So far, only in Chrome
- Disabling/enabling Chrome auto-complete doesn't seem to have any impact

The issue seems similar to the one reported here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6066, but the conditions not entirely the same (vertical scrolling instead of horizontal; not using overflow:hidden).  So, maybe the issue also happens under other conditions than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick fix for this, that is a bit janky sometimes, but involves adding an event handler for when you focus into an input in the slider.

Here's my code

```
$('.bx-viewport input').focusin(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {             // setTimeout makes sure that this runs after 
                                        // the original problem (it had a delay)
       $('.bx-viewport').scrollLeft(0); 
    }, 0);
});
```

So your solution should be to find out which element is getting a scrollLeft applied to it and set it to zero.

Heres the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jtuo5my0/7/